# getting continuous functions from a function defined over a compact set

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

$\mathbf{PROBLEM:}$ Let $X$, $Y$ be a spaces and $f : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $X$ is compact, prove that the function $g$, $h : Y → \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(y) = \sup \{ f(x, y)|x \in X\} $ and $h(y) = \inf \{f(x, y)|x \in X\}$ are continuous.

$\mathbf{ATTEMPT:}$ Because $X × \{y\}$ is compact, then $g$ and $h$ make sense since $f\restriction_{X × \{y\}}$ would be bounded. I want to prove this for $g$ and I suppose that the proof will be similar for $h$. I can only think of this:

I take an open bounded interval $(a,b)$, and I consider $C=g^{-1}[(a,b)]$. I want to prove that $C$ is open in $Y$. For see this, I take $c\in C$ and I'm going to prove that $c\in int(C)$. Because $g(c) = \sup \{ f(x, c)|x \in X\} $, the $f(x,c)<b$ dor each $x\in X$, even more, I can find $d\in X$ such that $f(c,d)\in (a,b)$. Now, because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}[(-\infty,b)]=D$ is an open set of $X \times Y$. It is easily to see that $X \times \{ c \} \subset D$, so, for tube lemma, there exist an open set $U$ of $Y$ such that $c\in U$ and $X \times U \subset D$.

Now, only I need to show that I can consider U small sufficiently such that for each $y\in U$, there exist $x\in X$ such that $f(x,y)>a$ and thus $f(x,y)\in (a,b)$, and therfore I could conclude that $U\in C$ is the desired open.

However, I don't get advance from here...

Comment: There are *more* open sets in $X \times Y$ than just $A \times B$-like sets (these form a base, sure, but it does *not* mean all open sets have that shape).

Comment: Hint: go pointwise: suppose $g(p,q) \in (c,d)$ what do you know? Also, use the lemma in your text about open neighbourhoods of sets of the form $X \times \{y\}$.

Comment: I don't understand your hint...how do you interpret $g(p,q)$?...lemma more similar about this, it say:  if $X$ is compact then for every space $Y$, the projection $X × Y\rightarrow Y$ is a closed map. I thought in using this but, I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: Rather $g(p) \in (c,d)$ then. The closed map idea also works but you need to use the closedness in the right way (as "inverse fibre continuity").

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks for your suggestions. I could advance a lot of with the problem. However, I don't get to finish yet. can you help me with any other suggestion for finish this problem please?...I edited in the question my attempt, there you'll find my new progress...again, thank you so much